# Where's the 2023 Qualified Dividends and Capital Gain Tax Worksheet?

Tags: united-states, taxes, qualified-dividend, tax-forms

When I google it, I just get the 2018 one, which I'm pretty sure doesn't work for 1040 2023. The IRS site just gives the Schedule D:
https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs-search?search=Qualified+Dividends+and+Capital+Gain+Tax+Worksheet

Answer (score 4):

It's part of the instructions for line 16 of Form 1040. Direct link [here](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi#w24811v12).

Comment: Generally. If it's called a worksheet in the US tax form instructions, you will find it in the instructions. If you are using tax prep software, they'll implement it as part of their system.